# Global Variables For Core Data Classes (Bad?, Good?)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, global-variables, swift3

I have a file called globals.swift

The code is very simple and looks like this.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

var g_workOrders = [Workorders]()
var g_services = [Service]()

//Shortcut method to get the viewcontext easily from anywhere.
func gm_getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //For unique constraints it will overwrite the data.
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

    return context
}
```

My data model is very simple, its a workorder which refers to a 'service' which in my context can be thought of as a description for the workorder.  Workorders can only have one 'service'.  A 'service' can belong to many workorders but does not have a relationship to many of them.  So its a one to one I believe still.

g_workOrders[] and g_services[] are NSManagedSubclasses that I created from the editor menu -> createNSManagedSubClasses.

I plan to use these arrays throughout the program to keep track of the current state of work orders and get info on a service at anytime.  Furthermore if I update the global variables and call save on the context it should save the database.  **This does currently work but my question is...is this good practice?** **Can any unexpected behavior result from doing it this way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is questionable for mainly two reasons: It hogs memory, and it has potential inconsistencies if the db changes and your array objects are not in sync.

You should use `NSFetchedResultsController` wherever you need this data. Core Data will do all optimizations for you and give you lots of functionality for free (e.g., ideal for table views).

Also, one of your statement is contradictory and might point to a design flaw:

> A 'service' can belong to many workorders but does not have a relationship to many of them.

This is definitely wrong. If the same `Service` can belong to many `Workorder`s, it should have a to-many relationship to the `Workorder` entity and a reverse to-one relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had this feeling I might be going about it the wrong way but wasn't sure why... It would appear what you are getting at is to access the data as I need it through coreData commands and fetches instead of trying to use a global variable to do it.  I think I'll try that approach, but this does pose an interesting question.  For each table I wanted to create a reference to the 'object' which holds certain states to it like 'on' or 'off'.  I was thinking putting that in the tablecontroller as a class variable, I wonder if this would cause the same issues.

Comment: The reason I was saying the service can belong to many work orders was because technically many work orders refer to a service template, but the service template only ever refers to one work order at a time.  This stuff has always been confusing for me the right way to do it :P.  In my head I was thinking the NSManagedSubclass would have this array variable on service which wouldn't make sense it should have just one variable to a workorder.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like a classic one to many with one service being connected to multiple work orders. You should have a service variable in work order, and an array of workOrders in service with a connection between those attributes.

Comment: If you're tracking data-inspecific state you should be using UserDefaults instead, if it's specific to instances of your data model, that should be loaded when the data is loaded.

Comment: Okay I think I can do this if I use primary keys and store that in the controller and use that to know what record I'm referring to for each cell

Answer (score 1):

You can do things this way, but you don't really need to.

You can simply get all the objects of the type you want with a fetch request whenever you need them. CoreData is highly optimized and cached so unless you're dealing with extreme numbers there shouldn't ever be a meaningful wait time. This way you know you will always have all the instances of your models without trying to manage their state in another place.

Also, if you have a connection between WorkOrders and Service in the database. (which you should), you definitely don't need to keep arrays of both of them to begin with.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me decide the direction to go